# I want to add a title with a Sitecounter

Tags: 2013, content-type

Can I add sitecounter to the title?

Thought about something like: `Project XX : Site 3`

Comment: How do you plan to create sites? through code c# or powershell?

Comment: Is it the site index within the collection or the number of subsites beneath it ?

Answer (score 0):

Not by out of the box functionality. Your best approach would be an Event Receiver which would control the creation of sites from within a List. E.g. you add an item to the list with the website information, event receiver creates the site and sets the title.

Hope this helps.